# Tablero con números donde caerán canicas en Java

Tags: java, array, matrices

Actualmente estoy iniciando en java y me pidieron hacer un código que indica lo siguiente:
[image: Actividad, Tablero y Canicas]

Ya no supe como continuar con el código, por lo que llevo esto.

```
import java.util.Random;

public static void main(String[] args) {

Random r = new Random();
int filas = 0, columnas = 0, puntos = 0, tiros = 0, suma = 0;
int[][] tablero = new int[8][6];
int[][] canicas = new int[8][6];

for (int x=0; x<tablero.length; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<tablero[0].length; y++) {
        puntos = (r.nextInt(3)+1)*2;
        tablero[x][y]=puntos;
        canicas[x][y]=0;
        System.out.print("  ["+tablero[x][y]+"]  ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

boolean follow = true;
if (follow = true) {
    
    filas = r.nextInt(tablero.length);
    columnas = r.nextInt(tablero[0].length);
    canicas[filas][columnas] = tablero[filas][columnas];
    tiros++;
    suma += canicas[filas][columnas];
} else {
    System.out.println("CASILLA OCUPADA..."+(filas+1)+","+(columnas+1));
}

System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
for (int x=0; x<tablero.length; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<tablero[0].length; y++) {
        if (canicas[x][y] !=0) {
            System.out.print("  ["+canicas[x][y]+"]  ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("  [ ]  ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}   

if (tiros == 5) {
    follow = false; 
}

}
```

El problema que me preocupa y me ha hecho estar estancado con el código, es al momento de que se seleccionen los 5 espacios donde cayeron las "canicas", me arroja esto al compilarlo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente selecciona uno y los cuatro restantes no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estás complicando mucho en el código que adjuntaste, aquí te echo una mano con `código` más simplificado para que puedas entenderle y no te enredes tanto.

Antes de empezar, cabe mencionar que el `código` va dentro del método `public static void main` así como tu código original.

En **primer lugar** se declaran todas las `variables`;

`acumulador_tiros`= contará los 5 tiros de canicas,

`suma` = sumará los puntos de las posiciones,

`tablero` = donde se guardarán los valores para después imprimir,

`canicas` = donde se guardarán los valores donde haya caído cada canica,

`premios` = donde se almacenarán los premios (se hace el llenado en las posiciones de acuerdo a los puntos que se ganen, del 10 al 30)

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int acumulador_tiros = 1, suma = 0;
    int [][] tablero = new int[8][6];
    String [][] canicas = new String[8][6];
    String [] premios = new String[31]; 
    
    premios[10] = "premio10"; premios[11] = "premio11"; premios[12] = "premio12";
    premios[13] = "premio13"; premios[14] = "premio14"; premios[15] = "premio15";
    premios[16] = "premio16"; premios[17] = "premio17"; premios[18] = "premio18";
    premios[19] = "premio19"; premios[20] = "premio20"; premios[21] = "premio21";
    premios[22] = "premio22"; premios[23] = "premio23"; premios[24] = "premio24";
    premios[25] = "premio25"; premios[26] = "premio26"; premios[27] = "premio27";
    premios[28] = "premio28"; premios[29] = "premio29"; premios[30] = "premio30";
```

**Segundo paso**, se llena e imprime el tablero con los valores:

```
    System.out.println("||||||||||||||||TABLERO||||||||||||||||");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++ ){
            
            tablero[i][j] = (r.nextInt(3)+1)*2;
            System.out.print("  ["+tablero[i][j]+"]  ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

**Tercer paso**, se hacen los tiros de las canicas, aquí lo que se hace es usar **números aleatorios** del **1 al 30**, y si cae un numero del **1 al 4** y la variable `acumulador_tiros` es menor o igual a 5, la canica cae en la **posición actual** que ha recorrido el ciclo `for` y la matriz `canicas` se llena con lo que la matriz `tablero` contiene en la posición que cayó la canica. Y finalmente se imprime.

```
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("||||||||||||||||CANICAS||||||||||||||||");
    int aleatorio;
    
    for(int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < 6; l++ ){
            
            aleatorio = r.nextInt(30)+1; 
            
            if(aleatorio <= 4 && acumulador_tiros <= 5){
                
                acumulador_tiros += 1;
                canicas[k][l] = String.valueOf(tablero[k][l]);
                suma += tablero[k][l];
                
            }else{
                canicas[k][l] = " ";
            }
            System.out.print("  ["+canicas[k][l]+"]  "); 
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

**Último paso**, se hace la validación sobre si la canica ha caído en la misma posición para reiniciar el juego, y si no, imprime la sumatoria de los puntos, imprime el `arreglo` con los premios y finalmente se imprime el premio que ha obtenido el jugador de acuerdo a los puntos sumados. Para esto, se le pasa como parámetro al `array premios` la suma de los puntos para imprimir el premio.

```
    System.out.println("\n");
    if(acumulador_tiros < 5){
        System.out.println("Han caido canicas en el mismo espacio, vuelva a lanzar.");
        
    }else{
        
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Sumatoria: " + suma + "\n");
        System.out.println("Lista de premios: ");
    
        for(int m = 0; m < premios.length; m++){
        
            if(premios[m] != null){
                System.out.println(premios[m]);
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Premio: " + premios[suma]);
    }
```

Intenta siempre ver la manera de optimizar tu código, analiza las posibilidades para después plasmarlo. Esto te ayudará a tener mejor lógica y código más legible.